# On release mode data not appearing flutter

Tags: android, flutter, directus

Everything is working perfectly on debug mode but when i release the app the data is not appearing (its like there is no data) and there is no errors in the terminal.
To note that i am using directus database and its still locally.

this is the view model

```
 Future<void> getCards({String value = ''}) async {
    try {
      dynamic response = await _homeRepository.getCards(value: value);
      _apiCardsResponse = ApiResponse.completed(response);
      _cardsList = _apiCardsResponse.data?.toJson()["cards"];
    } catch (error) {
      _apiCardsResponse = ApiResponse.error(error.toString());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

   @override
  void disposeValues() {
    _cardsList = List.empty();
  }

 get getCardsList => _cardsList;
```

This is the List view

```
ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: homeViewModel.getCardsList.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) => CardsComponent(
                            image:
                                '${context.resources.image.networkImagePath}${homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]['image']}',
                            // ?? '',
                            title:
                                homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]['name'] ?? '',
                            location: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                    ["location"] ??
                                '',
                            locationbtn: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                    ["locationbtn"] ??
                                '',
                            length: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                    ["length"] ??
                                '',
                            elevation: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                    ["elevation"] ??
                                '',
                            routeType: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                    ["route_type"] ??
                                '',
                            description: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                    ["description"] ??
                                '',
                            gallery: homeViewModel.getCardsList[index]
                                ['gallery'],
                          ))),
```

Comment: Add some code snippet to understand it better .

Comment: Post the code in the getCardsList method.

Comment: Have you added any network access in Manifest file?

Comment: @AliAlYousef no i havent't

Comment: in release mode you have to give permission to access network in Android,
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>